# Can you retrieve a list of contact groups using the Windows Phone 7 SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-7, contacts, windows-phone-7.1, addressbook

Using the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK is it possible to retrieve a list of contact groups that a user has setup?

I can retrieve all contacts, or search by name, email address etc, but can't see a way to tell:

```
A) What contact groups have been setup

or

B) Whether a particular contact is part of a group
```

Either would work fine for what i'm trying to do.

Is this possible with the latest SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it isn't available at the moment.

Delving around in the Microsoft.Phone.UserData namespace (which is where the Contact class lives) there is nothing to suggest that contact groups have any meaning in the API.